# How do I make the production log flush in Rails 3.2.11?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, production-environment

Right now, my rails app seems to write to production.log in intervals. How do I make the log update instantly? Or is there a way to force the log to flush?

Comment: FYI if you're still on 3.2.11 you're a few security patches behind, and you should consider updating to the latest Rails.